# Unity -> Vuforia 2.0 Upgrade License Required

Tags: unity-game-engine, upgrade, licensing, vuforia

My client has a Vuforia App running on Vuforia 2.0 and i need to update it with a new license key... the problem is... There is not license key handling in Vuforia 2!.

The common answer is "just update your whole system..." but it's not that simple, this project was terribly implemented and have a lot of hardcoded stuff on itself.

I already checked out the plugin scripts to see if i can just substitute the license key but, nothing found...

My question is... There is some way that i can just set up this license key?? Thanks!.

Comment: I would think not. You can contact sales for support but my guess is that Vuforia 2 is so old that they stopped it totally. So unfortunately, it could be you'd have to redo the AR part of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the hardlinked references in the system were attached to the game objects in the scene so, in the "migrating to vuforia 5 guidelines" document i just avoid the part of deleting the ARCamera and Cloud Reco from the scene, i would have missing references through the upgrading but, when completed, the system will be upgraded and will keep the linked references.

Thanks!.